# Select content after image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this code

```html
<div class="article">
  <img class="image-article" src="#" />
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quae quidem vel cum periculo est quaerenda"
</div>
```

I want to select the text content after the image, I want the text to be put into a `<p></p>`

Thanks for your replies !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use .wrap() on the next sibling element of the `img`

```js
$('.article .image-article').each(function() {
  if (this.nextSibling.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    $(this.nextSibling).wrap('<p></p>')
  }
})
```

```css
.article p {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article">
  <img class="image-article" src="#" />"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quae quidem vel cum periculo est quaerenda"
</div>
```